# Algorithm - Group/sort list to maximize minimum average group value

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, optimization

I'm looking for some help in writing an algorithm in Python that accomplishes the following:

> Given a list of real numbers, sort/group the list into n smaller lists such that the average minimum group value is maximized.

For example, consider grouping the list below into two lists - A and B, each with two elements.

```
lis = [1,1,2,2]
```

In the first scenario below, the minimum value of each list is 1, and as such the average minimum value is 1.

```
# Scenario 1
A = [1,2]
B = [1,2]

# Scenario 2
A = [1,1]
B = [2,2]
```

In the second scenario, the minimum value of A is 1, and the minimum value of B is 2, and so the average minimum value is 1.5. This arrangement is optimal.

It's clear that it's better to group values that are 'similar'. I could do this with [Jenks natural breaks optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenks_natural_breaks_optimization) (or one-dimensional k-means clustering). However, I'm not sure if my objective and the objective of Jenks optimization is (mathematically) equivalent.

Any help or input would be appreciated.

Edit: The smaller lists must all have the same size (assume the given list always divides into the smaller groups with no remainder).

Comment: Do the smaller lists all have to be the same size?

Comment: Yes, they do. Sorry, I should have stated that.

Comment: Sort the objects. Slice as desired. This yields the optimum solution - but you may have been asking the wrong question.

Comment: Yes, you just need to sort the list, then slice it up.  To divide it into n sublists of m elements each, put the smallest m in one sublist, the next smallest m in another, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to address this is to sort the numbers from smallest to largest and then to split the sorted list into `n` groups without further rearrangement. Any attempt to improve on this grouping will decrease the minimum of one of the groups and, therefore, the average of the minimums.

**An example may help explain why.**

Given a list with 12 numbers:

```
[94, 82, 61, 2, 96, 34, 87, 13, 82, 91, 61, 39]
```

The sorted list is:

```
[2, 13, 34, 39, 61, 61, 82, 82, 87, 91, 94, 96]
```

If we want `n=3` groups, those groups are then:

```
[[2, 13, 34, 39], [61, 61, 82, 82], [87, 91, 94, 96]]
```

So the average of the minimums is `avg(2,61,87)=50`.

**Can you do better than this? The answer is no.**

Moving any number from one group A to another group B will decrease the minimum of A without correspondingly increasing the minimum of B.

For instance, you might think that moving 61 to a different group would help.

One possible rearrangement is:

```
[[2, 13, 34, 61], [39, 61, 82, 82], [87, 91, 94, 96]]
```

This rearrangement has a value of `avg(2,39,87)=42`.

Another possible rearrangement is:

```
[[2, 13, 34, 39], [87, 61, 82, 82], [61, 91, 94, 96]]
```

This rearrangement has a value of `avg(2,61,61)=41`.

So you see, we cannot do better by moving 61. Likewise, we cannot do better by moving any number.

Answer (score 2):

It seems as if the simplest approach is to initially sort the list so that the lowest values are always grouped together, for example:

```
# Define the list of values to group
values = [1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12]

# Sort the values
values.sort()

# Split the values down into an even number of `n` groups
no_groups = 3
group_size = len(values) / no_groups
groups = []

for i in range(0, no_groups):
    groups.append(values[0:(group_size)])
    values = values[group_size:]

# Calculate the average minimum value of the groups
average_min = float(sum([g[0] for g in groups])) / no_groups

print(average_min)
```

But given your mention of Jenks and K-means clustering I'm concerned this is too simplistic and that I'm missing something?

Comment: I think you are right, the problem does not make a lot of sense since it boils down to sorting.